# Moved raid drives from a NAS enclosure to ubuntu 16.04 - one drive extremely slow

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I've moved my two raid1 drives from my [TrendNet TN-200 NAS](https://www.trendnet.com/products/nas-enclosure/TN-200) enclosure to a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. One of the drives is working fine, however the other is performing excruciatingly slow.

Here's some stats (check out the speed and time to finish on the rebuild):

```
cat /proc/mdstat                                                                

Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sdc2[2]
      2927642924 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [U_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  1.2% (35496384/2927642924) finish=20005.6min speed=2409K/sec

sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
    Version : 1.0
  Creation Time : Thu Jan  1 04:04:20 2015
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 2927642924 (2792.02 GiB 2997.91 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 2927642924 (2792.02 GiB 2997.91 GB)
 Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 2
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Wed Oct 18 16:26:25 2017
      State : clean, degraded, recovering
Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

 Rebuild Status : 1% complete

       Name : 1
       UUID : 52c46d6e:fb57141b:bde3b1d8:a4dae5d6
     Events : 137429

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       18        0      active sync   /dev/sdb2
   2       8       34        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdc2
```

I've tried a few different SATA cables and a different SATA port, with the same results. I also tried a few tries at running a short test with smartctl:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-97-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  
LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Self-test routine in progress 10%     21537         -
# 2  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      00%     21537         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               10%     21534         -
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm still a little new to Linux, but I know enough to be dangerous.

Comment: Did you increase the resync rate? http://www.remotecto.net/2014/03/26/speeding-up-mdadm-raid-rebuilds/

Comment: @ppetraki i I tried to:


    :~$ sudo echo 50000 > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
    -bash: /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min: Permission denied

Comment: @ppetraki Cancel that, I realized that I had the sudo in the wrong part. I've since done it as root and have not noticed a difference:
cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
50000
cat /proc/mdstat  
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sdc2[2]
      2927642924 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [U_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  2.5% (75648064/2927642924) finish=37434.4min speed=1269K/sec

Comment: try adding another 0 or two and make the min rsync speed equal to the max.